# How to retrieve document ID in firestore firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve the document ID in firestore database, I have successfully retrieved the data but not the ID for each document. Here is my code to retrieve the document data :

```
  const ref = query(
    collection(db, "vehicles"),
    where("type", "==", "motorbike")
  );
  onSnapshot(ref, (categories) =>
    setMotorList(categories.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()))
  );
  console.log(motorList);
} catch (e) {
  alert("failed load data " + e);
```

firebase config :

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import {
  getAuth,
  initializeAuth,
  getReactNativePersistence,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const auth = getAuth();

export default app;
```

How should I modify my code to retrieve the ID from vehicles database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The get the document ID, you can use the `snapshot`'s `doc.id` property like in the following lines of code:

```
onSnapshot(ref, (categories) =>
  categories.docs.map((doc) => ({id: doc.id, ...doc.data()}))
                               //
)
```

Please note that I have added the `ID` as a property to the object.